# Can't fill shape/letters

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, mask, texture

I used a custom textured brush to create a mask and create a dust and scratches effect on a logo, but I want to undo the effect and fully fill the letters, but I can't remove the texture I added. I thought I could find and remove the mask, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

[image: basic animation]

I can't find the mask in my layers panel.

[image: layers]

I want to figure this out, because I'm sure I'm missing something that I need to learn about illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I went into the appearance panel and kept poking to get to the top element, released the mask and deleted it.

[image]